# Why does NOT my first QUIP simulation with copper structure worked?

Tags: simulation

I would like to simulate energy of silicon lattice and trying to run QUIP or QUIPPY on Ubuntu.
I followed the instruction of [quippy installation guide](http://libatoms.github.io/QUIP/install.html) and compiled quip binary. However, 
the instant calculation of cubic Cu atomic properties with following command was not worked;

```
quip atoms_filename=test.xyz init_args='IP LJ' param_filename=Parameters/ip.parms.LJ.xml E
```

with the following error;

```
libAtoms::Hello World: 18/09/2019   22:15:02
libAtoms::Hello World: git version  https://github.com/libAtoms/QUIP.git,86ff37764-dirty
libAtoms::Hello World: QUIP_ARCH    linux_x86_64_gfortran
libAtoms::Hello World: compiled on  Aug 14 2019 at 21:23:38
libAtoms::Hello World: Random Seed = 80102523
libAtoms::Hello World: global verbosity = 0

Calls to system_timer will do nothing by default

Using calc args:
Using pre-relax calc args:
Using param_filename: Parameters/ip.parms.LJ.xml
Using init args: IP LJ
SYSTEM ABORT: Traceback (most recent call last)
File "{QUIPPY_PATH}/QUIP/src/libAtoms/xyz.c", line 359 kind unspecified
xyz_find_frames: empty file!
```

The content of test.xyz is as shown below (which is as same as the instruction):

```
4
Lattice="3.61 0 0 0 3.61 0 0 0 3.61" Properties=species:S:1:pos:R:3
Cu     0.000 0.000 0.000
Cu     0.000 1.805 1.805
Cu     1.805 0.000 1.805
```

Also, the content of ip.param.LJ.xml is as shown below (which is also as same as the instruction):

```
<LJ_params n_types="3" label="default">
<!-- dummy paramters for testing purposes, no physical meaning -->
<per_type_data type="1" atomic_num="29" />
<per_type_data type="2" atomic_num="79" />
<per_type_data type="3" atomic_num="47" />
<per_pair_data type1="1" type2="1" sigma="4.0" eps6="1.0" eps12="1.0" cutoff="6.0" energy_shift="T" linear_force_shift="F" />
<per_pair_data type1="2" type2="2" sigma="5.0" eps6="2.0" eps12="2.0" cutoff="7.5" energy_shift="T" linear_force_shift="F" />
<per_pair_data type1="1" type2="2" sigma="4.5" eps6="1.5" eps12="1.5" cutoff="6.75" energy_shift="T" linear_force_shift="F" />
<per_pair_data type1="3" type2="3" sigma="1.9" eps6="1.5" eps12="1.5" cutoff="4.5" energy_shift="T" linear_force_shift="F" />
</LJ_params>
```

Do anybody know what is wrong and how to deal with this error?
Should I use other version of QUIP?

Best,

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. I fear your question is off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: It might be better in Computational Science

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As you mentioned, this topic is not perfect programming problem, but related to programming. So I added the tag "simulation" and deleted the tag "fortran".